# How to implement User.Identity.Name in Global.asax on a new web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Visual Studio, I've created an entirely new ASP.NET Web Forms Application using their provided template.

I've done nothing to the code that VS auto-generates except add the following to `Global.asax.cs`:

```
string myself = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string me = User.Identity.Name;
```

String myself stores my current windows logon ID successfully. But string me is null, because when I debug, `User` is null. However, Visual Studio shows no errors before debugging.

How do I get the proper value for string me using `User.Identity.Name`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Input code in **Session_Start** :

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string myself = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    string me = User.Identity.Name;
    Response.Write("myself:" + myself + "<br>me:" + me);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. I had the code in Application_Start() before.

Comment: ... And a nice contrast between the WindowsIdentity vs. the User.Identity.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using? I don't remember off-hand but anonymous authentication may present a null or null like object in `User`.

Comment: I'd like it to use Windows authentication. I think I need to modify web.config <system.web> in order to implement this, but the things I've tried haven't worked.