# Redirect user to specific page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, global-asax

If user logs in to my website for the first time, they are redirected to page where they have to mandatorily provide required data and only then they are able to access website

I have removed the menus, and also on login confirmed if they are login for the first time they will be landed to this **(mandatory inputs)** page. But there's a possibility that they would manually enter the url and bypass this mandatory page which i want to avoid.

For this i used `Application_BeginRequest` but here i do not get the current users name so that i can process it further, i also used `Session_Start`, but it executes first time only,so next time still the bypass will work.

Is there anyway i can setup a redirect from central location and it will ensure on any page hit, if the user has logged in first time, he/she should be bounced back to this **mandatory** inputs page.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283255/how-to-implement-user-identity-name-in-global-asax-on-a-new-web-application

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Base Page Class/Controller and Inherit all your classes/Controllers from that.

And check the details their on the Page_Load event of Base page and redirect to the mandatory page if the user have not filled that yet.

```
public class BasePage : Page
    {
      protected BasePage()
      {
             this.Load += new EventHandler(BasePage_Load);
      }

    private void BasePage_Load(object Sender, EventArgs E)
    {
      //TODO: Add your code here for checking globally
    }
}

//====
//Other class inherited from Base page.
public partial class HomePage : BasePage
{
  //All your code goes here.
}
```